# Can't extend main class with anything but Activity

Tags: android

Hi
I am trying to extend my main entry point with a superclass (so I don't have to override onCreateOptionsMenu in each activity i got for example) but for some reason it seems I am not allowed to do this with the class I got set as my main entry point for my application in android.

For example: MainClass extends Activity works fine but MainClass extends mySuperClass where mySuperClass extends Activity does not work - anyone got any idea if I am doing something wrong or if this is an android specific issue?

Thanks for any help or input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Android Activity classes MUST extend an Activity base class. Your superclass definition must be missing something: post the class definition.

Comment: ups, more info heh. My classes are: public class SalesClient extends Menu  and public class Menu extends Activity  - if my SalesClient extend from Activity I dont get any errors. For the record the error I am getting is "The type Menu cannot be the superclass of SalesClient; a superclass must be a class"

Comment: Well, `Menu` is an existing class: what happens if you change the name to `MenuActivity`?

Comment: Yep: its probably complaining because it is referencing the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html interface. Check your `import` statements.